# Delete duplicate value in a column and merge, sum in the same row using openpyxl

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

Using openpyxl i could highlight the duplicates but i need to delete it and merge in the same row,
here's my code

```
import openpyxl

def isheet(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'home/index.html', {})
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]


        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
        #wb.create_sheet('Sheet1')
        wb.create_sheet('Sheet2')

        worksheet = wb.active
        
        sheets = wb.sheetnames
        print(sheets)

        worksheet = wb["Sheet1"]
        worksheet2 = wb["Sheet2"]
  
        # Duplicate finder


        red_text = Font(color="9C0006")
        red_fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE")
        dxf = DifferentialStyle(font=red_text, fill=red_fill)
        rule = Rule(type="duplicateValues", text="highlight", dxf=dxf)
        worksheet2.conditional_formatting.add('C1:C10000', rule)
        dup = worksheet2.conditional_formatting.add('C1:C10000', rule)

        excel_data = list()

        messages.success(request, 'BOM is Uploaded !')
        for row in worksheet2.iter_rows():
            row_data = list()
            for cell in row:
                row_data.append(str(cell.internal_value))
            excel_data.append(row_data)
        wb.save('C:/Users/'+getpass.getuser()+'/Downloads/VinBOM.xlsx')
        return render(request, 'index.html', {"excel_data":excel_data})
```

for example

Input

```
A    B      C        D
No  Qty    REF     Name
1    2    C1,C2     CAP
2    1     C3      CAP
3    1     R1      RES
```

Expected output

```
 A    B      C          D
No  Qty     REF        Name
1    3    C1,C2,C3     CAP
2    1      R1         RES
```

i am really clue less for the above problem, will be helpful if i get some hint

Comment: The answers to the previous questio.n still apply

Comment: @CharlieClark why this enmity with me.

Comment: No emnity, just pointing out you've asked the question before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This be done with openpyxl only, as suggest other methods may also work, but here is one;
This will sort the example from your Input image above. It will also work with the table of capacitors from the previous question.
By default the original data is expected to be from Columns B, C & D starting at row 2, Column A is just a row ID. Columns E onwards if present, are tied to the Name (Value) and copied to where the Name exists in the new table.

This code creates a dictionary of Dictionaries by Name (or Value) and holds the REF (Reference) values by Qty (Quantity). Then based on the name combines the reference values calculating the Quantity of each as they are combined.

1. It doesn't check for duplicates in the reference cell. I'd assume there are no capacitors, resistors etc with the same reference.
2. It doesn't sort the items in the reference cell, they are added as they come in the sheet.
3. No cell formatting is applied to the new sheet.

The output table is written to a new sheet as referenced by sheet object 'ws2'.

```
import openpyxl


combine_dict = {}
file = 'foo.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']
ws2 = wb['Sheet2']

quanty_col = 1
ref_col = 2
value_col = 3   # or Name column 

### List for Header names
headers_list = []
val_extra_dict = {}
### Create a dictionary of Quanty values by Reference
for row in ws1.iter_rows():
    if row[0].row == 1:
        ### Grab the headers for the new table
        for h in row:
            headers_list.append(h.value)
        continue
    qty = row[quanty_col].value
    reference = row[ref_col].value.strip()
    value = row[value_col].value
    ### Grab the extra columns that go with the Name (Value)
    value_extra = []
    ### Build combined dict
    for i in range(row[value_col].column, ws1.max_column-1):
        value_extra += [row[i].value]
    if value in combine_dict:
        if qty in combine_dict[value]:
            combine_dict[value][qty] += [reference]
        else:
            combine_dict[value].update({qty: [reference]})
    else:
        val_extra_dict[value] = value_extra
        combine_dict[value] = {qty: [reference]}

### Add the Headers to the table on the new sheet
ws2.append(headers_list)

### Combine the Reference values and calc the Total Qtys
for enum, (key, value) in enumerate(combine_dict.items(),1):
    totqty = 0
    reflist = ''
    for subkey, subval in combine_dict[key].items():
        cur_qty = combine_dict[key][subkey]
        totqty += subkey * len(subval)
        total = len(cur_qty)
        for i in subval:
            reflist += f'{i},'
    ### Append combined data to the sheet including the extra columns
    ws2.append([enum,
                totqty,
                reflist,
                key] +
                val_extra_dict[key]
                )

wb.save(file)
```